# iphone, xcode, valid architectures importance

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I just would like to know what is thew importance of setting Valid architectues ( armv7, armvs ) in your xcode projects? At what level of the SDK does that become important? Coredata? some caching issue?
not trying to diminish it but to understand the reason it exists.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between "Architectures" and "Valid Architectures" in Xcode Build Settings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701188/whats-the-difference-between-architectures-and-valid-architectures-in-xcode)

Comment: it is for what architecture the code get compiled to. armv7s can run armv7, but not viceversa, so if you compiler only for armv7s you cannot run on an iphone4s and below. usually when developing for speeding up compiling you can set BUILD_FOR_ACTIVE_ARCHITECTURE_ONLY to yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [XCode Buid setting reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW51)

Specifies the architectures for which the binary may be built. During the build, this list is intersected with the value of ARCHS build setting; the resulting list specifies the architectures the binary can run on. If the resulting architecture list is empty, the target generates no binary.