# Compiling framework with armv7 and armv7s

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-frameworks

I am trying to build a static library on xcode 5 and i am aggregating the libraries for iphone simulator and iphone device for creating a framework. But, at the last i am getting error 
"No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=armv7, VALID_ARCHS=i386 x86_64)" 
while running the run script for framework.

I am trying to compile it for armv7 and armv7s both.

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Unless you actually use the armv7s new instructions, you really don't need it at all. All it does otherwise is flag you in the store as "Optimized for iphone 5". It does increase the size of your binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem finally. In my case, i had some dependent project for my static library project. In the dependent project settings, the ARCH was armv7. I made that to 'Standard architectures (armv7, armv7s)' and it compiled successfully. For my static library project, the setting are as follows:

Architectures: Standard architectures (armv7, armv7s)

Base SDK: Latest iOS (iOS 7.0)

Build Active Architectures Only: NO

Supported Platforms: iphonesimulator iphoneos

Valid Architectures: arm64 armv7 armv7s i386

Answer (score 0):

See [What's the difference between "Architectures" and "Valid Architectures" in Xcode Build Settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701188/whats-the-difference-between-architectures-and-valid-architectures-in-xcode) :

In short, XCode use intersection between ARCHS and VALID_ARCHS, which in your case is empty as the 2 have no common architecture (hence the error you get)
Adding armv7 to VALID_ARCHS might solve the problem.

Comment: In my xcode settings, i have ARCHS (armv7, armv7s) and VALID_ARCHS is (armv7, armv7s, arm64, x86_64, i386). If i am building for simulator then it is working fine but showing the error for device.

Comment: have you set 'build active architecture only' to NO? Have you found the generated binary in your XCode build directory ? (Organizer->Projects, Find your project, then click the link-arrow next to its 'derived data' folder, go find Build>Products folder, and see what binaries of your library are inside)

Comment: 'build active architecture only' is set to NO. I have checked the binary it is creating while simulator is selected. It is creating as expected. But showing error while building for device. In build settings ARCHS is 'Standard architectures (armv7, armv7s)'. I have no idea why it is showing error only for device.

Comment: I don't understand why either, sorry. Only weird thing is that you provided one value for ARCHS and VALID_ARCHS in your question (with no armv7 value in VALID_ARCHS) - as they were reported in your error - and in your comment you said you DID put a more complete list of values in VALID_ARCHS (including armv7). Do you have several projects in a same workspace ? If so, are you editing the good build settings ?

Comment: Yes, i do have multiple projects in my workspace. Initially, the project was not compiling even for simulator. At that time, my settings was ARCHS 'Standard architectures (armv7, armv7s)' and VALID_ARCHS (armv7, armv7s, arm64). After getting the error "No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=armv7, VALID_ARCHS=i386 x86_64)", i have added x86_64 and i386 to VALID_ARCHS. Then it stated compiling for simulator but but for device.

Comment: Ok, and are you compiling directly your static library project, or is it automatically as another project dependency ?

Comment: I am compiling my aggregate target. The project is having two targets,  one for static library and other one for aggregate.

Comment: I have a third party framework linked with my static library. I dont know if that framework is compiled for armv7s. Could it be the issue that third party framework is not compiled for armv7s?