# What is the different between "the binary is targeted " vs "the binary may be built" iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am new in building apps for iOS. There is an excellent answer about  the difference between “Architectures” and “Valid Architectures” in Xcode Build Setting  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701188/whats-the-difference-between-architectures-and-valid-architectures-in-xcode/12701209#12701209)
But i still don't understand the meaning of "the  binary is targeted " vs "the binary may be built". What are the different between them . Can everyone clarify them ? . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Valid Architectures` tells the ability and `Architectures` tells what you want.

Give you an example:

Though you can make `armv7`/`armv7s`/`arm64` binary (set `armv7 armv7s arm64` in Valid Architectures), but the only architecture you want to build is `armv7` (set `armv7` in Architectures). Intersect Architectures with Valid Architectures is `armv7`

"The binary is targeted" is the binary you finally build and "the binary may be build" is the binary you can build.

Comment: @KudoCC.Thanks for your answer. but  is "the binary may be build" needed or not?. When do we use "the binary may be build"?

Comment: @BoBo I reference from the comment in the accepted answer of your link from Jeremy W. Sherman. "Most of the time, you don't want VALID_ARCHS. If you were writing inline asm for only certain architectures, you might change VALID_ARCHS to reflect that your code is no longer intended for any but those architectures. Mostly, though, it's just a cue to you from Xcode that indicates which architectures it can build for, and you pick from there for your ARCHS"