# Getting error compiling framework SDK in Xcode 10

Tags: ios, xcode, mobile, llvm, xcode10

I am getting the following while trying to compile a framework SDK in Xcode 10.

```
unable to load standard library for target 'armv7s-apple-ios8.0-simulator'
unable to load standard library for target 'armv7-apple-ios8.0-simulator'
unable to load standard library for target 'arm64-apple-ios8.0-simulator'
```

I was able to compile the framework with Xcode 9 without any problem, I get only this error when I use Xcode 10.

I tried everything from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51558933/error-unable-to-load-standard-library-for-target-arm64-apple-ios10-0-simulator), but anything works.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Any solution for this ?

Comment: For me it's still simply select Generic iOS devices or any real device to compile